# SQL statement updates only one user's data

Tags: php, sql, jquery-ui, jquery

```
<?php

    function get_user_id($username) {
        return mysql_result(mysql_query("Select id From users Where username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "'"), 0);
    }

    $sql = "select * from rating 
    WHERE user_id=" . get_user_id($myusername) . "
            ORDER BY punkte ASC";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $catid = $row['rating_id'];
        $catname = $row['song_id'];
        echo "<li id='item_$catid' class='ui-state-default'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s'></span>$catname</li>";
    }
    ?>
```

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, I found the mistake, it was quite stupid:

```
    $catid = $row['rating_id'];
    $catname = $row['song_id'];
```

It should be:

```
$catid = $row['song_id'];
$catname = $row['song_name'];
```

So, thanks to all! As always: You can't figure it out before you post a question to Stackoverflow :)

Comment: Please tell me what value you are getting from get_user_id($myusername)) by doing echo exit.

Comment: +1 for well written first question - welcome to stackoverflow ,)

Comment: Thanks! I discovered what was wrong and now I updated the question to another one.

Answer (score 1):

For your new question, you can solve it with a inner join:

```
select s.song_name from rating r
inner join songs s on s.song_name_id = r.song_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner join

> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

$catid = $row['rating_id']; //rating id is not related to song

TO

$catid = $row['song_id'];
$catname = $row['song_name'];